# Is the opposite of abstract "concrete", "particular", "specific" or other word?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions

I asked a question in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3313092/678038).

> To illustrate this, I am trying to find a `concrete example`.
>
> let $(A_n)_{n=2}^\infty$ denote the sequence of sets $A_n$
>
> where $A_n$ is the set of primes $\le n (n\ge 2)$.
>
> $A_2={2},\ A_3={2,3},A_4=A_3,A_5={2,3,5},...$

where by "abstract", I mean the conceptual term `sequence of sets`, by "concrete example", I mean ({2},{2,3},{2,3,5},...)

similarly, `a number` is an example of "abstract", 1, 2, 0.5 are examples of the "opposite of abstract"

In this context, Is the opposite of abstract "concrete", "particular", "specific" or other word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, "particular", "specfic" and "concrete" are synonymous.  You could use any term.

Wiktionary gives "Concrete (adjective):... 3. Particular, specific, rather than in general"

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of abstract is defined

Comment: Please add reference to support your answer.